# Pagination over ordered query SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query that gets a list of objects, when i order_by on a foreign column, the pagination doesn't work properly, it doesn't give the expected output.

Here is the query:

```
imports = (
    TImports.query.options(
        Load(TImports).raiseload("*"),
        joinedload("authors"),
        joinedload("dataset"),
    )
    .filter_by_scope(scope)
    .filter(or_(*filters))
    .order_by(order_by)
    .paginate(page=page, error_out=False, max_per_page=limit)
)
```

The order_by is dynamic

I tried to use subquerys to no success

Comment: I'm not sure what version you are using but you can try to use offset and limit in SQLAlchemy directly?